# Ошибка при попытке запуска проекта в VS 2017 Remote Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка

Решил поэкспериментировать с удаленным дебаггом, после его настройки на удаленном компьютере (он находится в локальной сети), и указав в настройках проекта его IP адрес (ну перед этим, естественно поставив галочку "Использовать удаленный компьютер"), выскакивает ошибка после запуска проекта:

> Ошибка при запуске проекта: Не удалось запустить программу 
>   "D:......\bin\debug\Program.exe" 
>  
>  Не удается найти
>   указанный файл

Естественно, я проверял полностью путь до файла, и он верный, и соответственно, файл там находится.

PS В качестве удаленного компьютера, используется Windows 10

Comment: путь до файла проверяли на удаленной машине?

Comment: На удаленной машине, нету даже диска D.

Comment: Для этого потребуется, что-ли создать диск D, и полный путь на удаленной машине?

Comment: @Михаил Или перенести файл с проектом на основной машине на `C:`.

Comment: нет, для этого потребуется расшареная папка на удаленной машине, отдельный билд-конфиг для удаленной отладки и собственно билд на эту шару.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала удаленной отладки клиентского приложения необходимо выполнить следующее:

**На удаленной машине** (виртуальной или реальной не важно):

- у тестовой машины должен быть либо фиксированный адрес, либо сетевое имя, прописанное и автоматически обновляемое в DNS сервисе, чтобы не менять настройки проекта в дальнейшем.
- настраиваем сетевую папку, доступную на чтение и запись с машины разработчика, для того чтобы не заниматься копированием каждого билда в ручную.
- необходимо установить Remote Debuger. Для этого нужно скопировать из папки `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger` версию отладчика нужной разрядности либо скачать инсталлятор по ссылкам из статьи [Remote Debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging) в документации Microsoft. Не знаю что именно требуется скачивания официального инсталлятора, но моему LiveId явно чего-то не хватило.
- прописываем запуск msvsmon.exe в автозагрузку при логине пользователя любым удобным способом (групповые политики, ярлык в папке SturtUp, планировщик заданий, logon-скрипт). Можно пропустить этот пункт и запускать каждый раз ручками.
- настраиваем эталонного пользователя для входа в систему и тестирования приложения, выдаем ему необходимые права и, самое главное, отбираем все заведомо лишние права.

**В настройках проекта:**

- создать отдельную конфигурацию для удаленной отладки
- в разделе Build созданной конфигурации в параметре Output folder указать сетевую папку удаленной машины
- в разделе Debug выбрать Remote debug

**Процесс отладки клиентского приложения**

- перед отладкой нужно явно запустить билд решения, при этом файлы приложения будут скопированы в сетевую папку удаленной машины (если сделано все, перечисленное выше). В принципе это требуется сделать только один раз, при последующих изменения кода в студии, билд будет запускаться автоматически, как при локальной отладке.
- подключиться к удаленной машине любым клиентом, позволяющим взаимодействие с рабочим столом.
- запускаем msvsmon.exe, если это не было сделано автоматически при логине.
- в студии запускаем отладку обычным образом, при этом на удаленной машине запуститься отлаживаемое приложение. Все точки останова и исключения будут обрабатываться на машине разработчика.

---

Для отладки web- и других серверных приложений лучше установить Remote Debuger  в качестве службы.

Comment: Все разжевано) Спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил неделю назад для своих коллег в локальную вики писал, вот и тут пригодилось =)

Comment: Значит, не один я такой, дебаггер =)

Answer (score 1):

Этот файл должен находиться на удаленном компьютере, причем в той же папке, что и на хосте. А еще на удаленном компьютере должен работать [Remote Tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging).

Для автоматического копирования собранного файла на отладочную машину можно использовать вот эти заклинания в Post-Build Step:

```
robocopy $(TargetDir) \\RemoteMachine\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\
if errorlevel 1 exit 0 else exit %errorlevel%
```